# Using a woocommerce function in your wordpress child-theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a e-commerce site using wordpress and woocommerce and the theme The Retailer.

The theme does not have breadcrumbs links and now I have decided that I want to add them. From my understanding Woocommerce should have support for this.

I will enable the breadcrumbs links on the `single-product.php` page. The woocommerce documentation says that I should use `<?php woo_breadcrumbs(); ?>` function to enable the breadcrumb links.

But when I add the `<?php woo_breadcrumbs(); ?>` statement to my `single-product.php` page I get a fatal error saying that the function is undefined. My questions is how to make my child-theme "recognise" this function?

If I use "brute force" method and copy all the original woocommerce breadcrumbs code (found in: `woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumbs.php`) to my own function inside my themes `functions.php` the breadcrumbs are working, although I do not get the delimiters and other things that should come with them...

This is not an elegant solution. Instead there must be some way for me to "register" the woocommerce breadcrumbs function inside my theme so that I can use the standard recommended woocommerce prodcedure. How would I do this?

Thank you for your help! Kind regards, Lukas

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that would work I guess:

Copy the "shop" folder to your theme from the below destination

```
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates
```

And paste it inside your theme. I hope that will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there must be a better way to access the woocommerce functions?

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is woo-commerce ready, there is a file "theme-woocommerce.php" in includes folder; Thats were you can do the modification; You may want to create a child theme as well, in case you want to update your theme in a future

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry but I can not find any file like that. The theme has the woocommerce folder where a number of .php files are included (files that my theme modify). But on a more general note, how do you call a woocommerce function from within a theme?

Comment: sorry, i didnt realize your theme was not from woothemes; you may find  some solutions here:http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/